# push replaces the old value in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Maybe its because I have been working all day and I can't see the problem. But in the following code the alert only shows the last added value and doesn't push the value in the array. :(

```
window.sortControl = {
            sortControlPanel: $('div.sortControl'),
            simpleSortCriteriaList: $('div.sortControl .simple'),
            advancedSortCriteriaList: $('div.sortControl .advanced'),
            dropDownExpander: $('div.sortControl .dropDownExpand.primary'),
            dropDownContent: $('div.sortControl .dropdownContent.primary'),
            simpleSortCriteria: $('div.sortControl .sortcriteria.simple a'),
            simpleSortCheckboxes: $('.simple .checkbox'),
            openAdvancedButton: $('.openAdvanced'),
            backtoSimpleButton: $('.backtoSimple'),
            advancedDropdownContent: $('div.sortControl .advanced .dropdownContent'),
            advancedDropdownExpander: $('div.sortControl .advanced .dropDownExpand')
        };

 $.each(sortControl.advancedDropdownContent.parent(), function () {

        var dropdownContent = $(this).find('.dropdownContent');
        var input = $(this).find('input');

        $(this).find('.dropDownExpand').live('click', function (event) {
            sortControl.advancedDropdownContent.not(dropdownContent).hide('fast');
            dropdownContent.toggle('fast');
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        var currentSelectedGroups = [];

        $(this).find('li a').bind('click', function (event) {

            var criteria = $(this).text();
            //if (!currentSelectedGroups.inArray($(this).attr('class'), true)) {
            input.attr('value', criteria);
            currentSelectedGroups.push($(this).attr('class'));

            //}

            dropdownContent.toggle('fast');

            event.preventDefault();
            alert(currentSelectedGroups);
        });

    });
```

Some of the html:

```
<div class='sortcriteria advanced'>

                <label>Sort by: </label>
                <div class='controlWrapper'>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='Any' value='Any' class='dropDownExpand'>
                    <span  class='icon dropDownExpand' title='Select property type'></span>
                    <ul class='dropdownContent'>
                        <li><a href='#' class='price'>Price ascending</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='price'>Price descending</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='party'>Party size ascending</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='party'>Party size descending</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='bedrooms'>Number of bedrooms ascending</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='bedrooms'>Number of bedrooms descending</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='star'>Star rating ascending</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='star'>Star rating descending</a></li>                           
                    </ul>
                </div> ...
```

1. There are no JavaScript errors.
2. Content and this script get loaded via ajax
3. All other statements do what they are supposed to

Comment: Where is `var currentSelectedGroups = [];` declared?  Is it in the global scope where it survives from one click to the next?  Or is it a local variable somewhere and getting destroyed and recreated and thus it only ever contains the value you just added to it?

Comment: I updated and question with more sections of the code

Comment: I don't know what your intention is, but you're creating a new `currentSelectedGroups` element for each iteration of the Array.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think i am going blind. been at it today for 9 hours...its just being blind. please add your comment as an answer

Comment: Also be aware that with `$(this).find('.dropDownExpand').live('click',...`, the `.live()` handler will not confine itself to descendants of `this`. Basically, you're doing `$('.dropDownExpand').live('click',...` once for each iteration, so you're likely binding redundant handlers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move `var currentSelectedGroups = [];` outside the each loop. You declare it once for every instance - they all work on their own version of the variable because it lives in the local scope of the each function.

Remember in javascript functions = scope

Comment: I am sweating with shame to miss that one

Comment: Don't, we all have long days every once in a while, sometimes you just can't see the forest because of all the trees ;)

Answer (score 1):

As I asked you (and suspected) in my earlier comment, you need to move:

```
var currentSelectedGroups = [];
```

outside the `.each()` loop.  As it is you are re-initializing it to an empty array in each iteration of the loop so it never has more than one value in it.  You can do that like this:

```
var currentSelectedGroups = [];

$.each(sortControl.advancedDropdownContent.parent(), function () {

        var dropdownContent = $(this).find('.dropdownContent');
        var input = $(this).find('input');

        $(this).find('.dropDownExpand').live('click', function (event) {
            sortControl.advancedDropdownContent.not(dropdownContent).hide('fast');
            dropdownContent.toggle('fast');
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $(this).find('li a').bind('click', function (event) {

            var criteria = $(this).text();
            //if (!currentSelectedGroups.inArray($(this).attr('class'), true)) {
            input.attr('value', criteria);
            currentSelectedGroups.push($(this).attr('class'));

            //}

            dropdownContent.toggle('fast');

            event.preventDefault();
            alert(currentSelectedGroups);
        });

    });
```