# Here i am trying to push the all the object in array, but its remember the last value only, pls give some suggestion

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my code, I have pushed the data into data[], but all the data showing the same content which is the last.

```
var myObj = {};
var data = [];

for (var kl = 0; kl < reportCriteriaIdData.length; kl++) {
    myObj["id"] = [myId];
    myObj[thisobj.scFilterLabel[0]] = [reportCriteriaIdData[kl].text];
    myObj["label"] = [reportCriteriaIdData[kl].text];
    myObj["index"] = [kl];
    data.push(myObj);
}
```

Comment: You keep pushing a *reference* to one and the same object, which you keep modifying. You need to create a new `var myObj = {}` inside each loop iteration.

Comment: i am getting result like this:
Controller
:
["10.106.190.72"]
id
:
["10.106.190.72"]
index
:
[1]
label
:
["10.106.190.72"]
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Controller
:
["10.106.190.72"]
id
:
["10.106.190.72"]
index
:
[1]
label
:
["10.106.190.72"]

Comment: Brilliant
Thanks

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522385/push-replaces-the-old-value-in-the-array

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize an empty object inside the `for` loop so that each time a new object is created and pushed in the array:

```
var data = []; 

for(var kl = 0; kl< reportCriteriaIdData.length; kl++)
{  
  //initialize empty object
  var myObj = {};
  myObj["id"] = [myId];
  myObj[thisobj.scFilterLabel[0]] = [reportCriteriaIdData[kl].text];
  myObj["label"] = [reportCriteriaIdData[kl].text];
  myObj["index"] = [kl];
  data.push(myObj);

}
```